# Errors every time I use 'apt install' because of old kernels

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

I upgraded tot 17.04 (from Ubuntu Gnome 16.10) recently and now get the following errors every time I try `apt install` or `apt upgrade`. I have tried removing the packages that appear to raise the errors, but nothing worked so far.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-58-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 322 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 254844 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.8.0-58-generic (4.8.0-58.63) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.8.0-58-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-58-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-58-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-58-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-58-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-58-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic (4.8.0-59.64) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.8.0-59-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-59-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-59-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-58-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-59-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It appears some other 17.04 packages weren't entirely installed because of this which seems to raise some other problems (such as reboots when getting out of suspend). How do I get rid of these errors/how do I get 17.04 fully working?

Edit 1:

```
rienheuver@rien-emperor:~$ dkms status
i915_bpo, usbc: added
i915, usbc, 4.8.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I have a Dell XPS 13 9350, so usbc seems relevant. But I'm not sure I use any of these and/or if they are still relevant/needed.

Comment: Do you know what you're using dkms for? That seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: I updated the answer with dkms-info

Comment: @Zanna Please help. I have the same problem and my dhms status is  ```nvidia, 390.138, 4.15.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.138, 5.4.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.138, 5.4.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.138, 5.4.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed```. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @NikhilShrivastava sorry my friend, I don't have the knowledge to solve that. No experience with nvidia myself. Please do consider [asking a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with all your system details and hopefully someone else will be able to help you out. All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some crappy DKMS packages. I suggest to remove them:

```
sudo dkms remove i915/usbc --all
sudo dkms remove i915_bpo/usbc --all
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and I've been struggling for so long to resolve it, could you please help. My dkms status is ```nvidia, 390.138, 4.15.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.138, 5.4.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.138, 5.4.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.138, 5.4.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed```.