# Apt autoremove failed to fully uninstall old kernels, now they block apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, initramfs, linux-headers

I was trying to remove some old linux-kernels by using `sudo apt autoremove` 
as suggest by `apt-get upgrade`. However the autoremoval was unsuccessful. Now, trying to remove an old kernel yields `sudo apt remove linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done    
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-122-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 774 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 363205 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-112-generic: No such     file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-112-    generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-112-generic     /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-112-    generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
mktemp: failed to create directory via template     ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_XXXXXX’: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic (--    remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic (4.4.0-116.140) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-116-generic: No such     file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-116-    generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-116-generic     /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-116-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-116-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-116-    generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic: No     such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
mktemp: failed to create directory via template     ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_XXXXXX’: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-119-generic: No such     file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-119-    generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-119-generic     /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-119-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-119-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-119-    generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-119-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-119-generic: No     such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
mktemp: failed to create directory via template     ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_XXXXXX’: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic (--    remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic (4.4.0-121.145) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-121-generic: No such     file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-121-    generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-121-generic     /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-121-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-121-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-121-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-121-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-121-    generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-121-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-121-generic: No     such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
mktemp: failed to create directory via template     ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_XXXXXX’: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic (--    remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Removing linux-    image-extra-4.4.0-122-generic (4.4.0-122.146) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-122-generic: No such     file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-122-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-122-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-122-generic     /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-122-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-122-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-122-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-122-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-122-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-122-    generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-122-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-122-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-122-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
mktemp: failed to create directory via template ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_XXXXXX’: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-122-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-122-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were     encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-122-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The fact that the first package does not print the error message "Please install the linux-headers-..." is because I installed the -112 headers manually via `sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic_4.4.0-112.135_amd64.deb` as a test. Otherwise, the error message would be the same for all packages.

I would be very glad for any input on this situation.

P.S: There are related problems [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952882/errors-every-time-i-use-apt-install-because-of-old-kernels) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898499/why-there-is-an-update-initramfs-error-when-removing-a-kernel-by-dpkg), but there the removal was inhibited by dkms packages and lack of space, respectively, which do not seem to apply here.

EDIT 1: As requested, some more diagnosis. `df`:

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev             16403560         0   16403560   0% /dev
tmpfs             3285556      9988    3275568   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6   20027260  15318552    3668324  81% /
tmpfs            16427776     31132   16396644   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16427776         0   16427776   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p7  269994584  82741016  173515584  33% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p2      98304     28796      69508  30% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1      1953513540 166939096 1786574444   9% /windows
tmpfs             3285556         8    3285548   1% /run/user/108
tmpfs             3285556        48    3285508   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p8   86410236     99712   86310524   1% /media/**/SSD         Share
```

`df -i`:

```
Filesystem         Inodes   IUsed      IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev              4100890     652    4100238    1% /dev
tmpfs             4106944     958    4105986    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6    1281120  412841     868279   33% /
tmpfs             4106944     211    4106733    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             4106944       5    4106939    1% /run/lock
tmpfs             4106944      16    4106928    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p7   17154048 1441660   15712388    9% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p2          0       0          0     - /boot/efi
/dev/sda1      1786771052  194329 1786576723    1% /windows
tmpfs             4106944      13    4106931    1% /run/user/108
tmpfs             4106944      29    4106915    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p8   86376060      44   86376016    1% /media/**/SSD Share
```

`dpkg -l | grep linux-image`:

```
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic                 4.4.0-101.124                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic                 4.4.0-103.126                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic                 4.4.0-104.127                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic                 4.4.0-108.131                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic                 4.4.0-109.132                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic                 4.4.0-124.148                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic                 4.4.0-127.153                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic                  4.4.0-31.50                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic                  4.4.0-47.68                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic                  4.4.0-51.72                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic                  4.4.0-53.74                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic                  4.4.0-57.78                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic                  4.4.0-59.80                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic                  4.4.0-62.83                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic                  4.4.0-63.84                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic                  4.4.0-64.85                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic                  4.4.0-66.87                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic                  4.4.0-70.91                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic                  4.4.0-71.92                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic                  4.4.0-72.93                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic                  4.4.0-75.96                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic                  4.4.0-78.99                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic                  4.4.0-79.100                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic                  4.4.0-81.104                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic                  4.4.0-83.106                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic                  4.4.0-87.110                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic                  4.4.0-89.112                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic                  4.4.0-91.114                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic                  4.4.0-93.116                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic                  4.4.0-96.119                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic                  4.4.0-97.120                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic                  4.4.0-98.121                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic           4.4.0-101.124                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic           4.4.0-103.126                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic           4.4.0-104.127                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic           4.4.0-108.131                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic           4.4.0-109.132                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic           4.4.0-112.135                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic           4.4.0-116.140                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic           4.4.0-119.143                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic           4.4.0-121.145                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-122-generic           4.4.0-122.146                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-124-generic           4.4.0-124.148                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic           4.4.0-127.153                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic            4.4.0-31.50                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic            4.4.0-47.68                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic            4.4.0-51.72                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic            4.4.0-53.74                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic            4.4.0-57.78                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic            4.4.0-59.80                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic            4.4.0-62.83                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic            4.4.0-63.84                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic            4.4.0-64.85                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic            4.4.0-66.87                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic            4.4.0-70.91                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic            4.4.0-71.92                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic            4.4.0-72.93                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic            4.4.0-75.96                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic            4.4.0-78.99                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic            4.4.0-79.100                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic            4.4.0-81.104                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic            4.4.0-83.106                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic            4.4.0-87.110                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-89-generic            4.4.0-89.112                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-91-generic            4.4.0-91.114                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic            4.4.0-93.116                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic            4.4.0-96.119                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic            4.4.0-97.120                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic            4.4.0-98.121                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                           4.4.0.127.133                                amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

`ls /boot`:

```
abi-4.4.0-124-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-4.4.0-127-generic         retpoline-4.4.0-124-generic
config-4.4.0-124-generic      retpoline-4.4.0-127-generic
config-4.4.0-127-generic      System.map-4.4.0-124-generic
efi                           System.map-4.4.0-127-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-124-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.4.0-127-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-127-generic
memtest86+.bin                vmlinuz-4.4.0-127-generic.efi.signed
memtest86+.elf
```

For reference, my current kernel is 
`uname -r
4.4.0-127-generic`

postinst.d/intramfs-tools file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

version="$1"
bootopt=""

[ -x /usr/sbin/update-initramfs ] || exit 0

# passing the kernel version is required
if [ -z "${version}" ]; then
    echo >&2 "W: initramfs-tools: ${DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE:-kernel     package} did not pass a version number"
    exit 2
fi

# exit if kernel does not need an initramfs
if [ "$INITRD" = 'No' ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# absolute file name of kernel image may be passed as a second argument;
# create the initrd in the same directory
if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    bootdir=$(dirname "$2")
    bootopt="-b ${bootdir}"
fi

# avoid running multiple times
if [ -n "$DEB_MAINT_PARAMS" ]; then
    eval set -- "$DEB_MAINT_PARAMS"
    if [ -z "$1" ] || [ "$1" != "configure" ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
fi

# we're good - create initramfs.  update runs do_bootloader
INITRAMFS_TOOLS_KERNEL_HOOK=1 update-initramfs -c -t -k "${version}" ${bootopt} >&2
```

Comment: These kinds of errors usually pop up after a user unwisely deletes package-manager-placed files using `rm` instead of using apt, turning an easy-to-fix disk-full error into a series of more-painful file-not-found errors. Could that be the case here?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `df` and `df -i` and `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` and `ls /boot`

Comment: So far I applied only apt-get and dpkg commands and tried the currently shown answer as well as the (now deleted) answer.  This did not (atleast to my knowledge) worsen the problem, but I cannot be sure entirely.

Comment: Now that I thought about it, earlier this morning I did delete the contents of the /tmp folder (unwise as that may have been without stopping all services). Could this have an influence here? I was not aware that anything to this issue would be stored there?

Comment: Deleting items in /tmp are unlikely to have an effect. Please edit your question to include the complete output of `uname -r`. Your problem looks fairly typical - not difficult to fix, but perhaps a bit tedious.

Comment: my current kernel is `4.4.0-127-generic`

Comment: Can you include the contents of the three `postinst.d` files.

Comment: I included the postinst.d scripts.  But shoudn't these files be identical for all Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installations?

Comment: @user535733 I just want to notify you, that I added all information that you asked for, in case the notifications did not reach you. Please disregard this comment entirely, if you have seen already seen the latest edit.

Comment: Try `sudo apt remove linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic`. Please show us the complete output of that command.

Comment: @user535733 done, you can now find this in the main body of the question.

Comment: Try `sudo touch /boot/System.map-4.4.0-112-generic` to create a dummy file for dpkg to remove. Then try `sudo apt remove linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic` again. Everything you need to know is right there in the error messages.

Comment: @user535733 "Everything you need to know is right there in the error messages." This was absolutely correct.  Thank you for pointing it out (unironically). I have too often seen error logs as some sort of magic script that I could never understand, but I went through it, line by line, and actually solved the problem. I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: Glad to see you got it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a (very simple) answer to this problem.

It turns out that the answer to this particular problem can be found in the following line from the error log. All other errors and missing files are just symptoms of this problem:

```
mktemp: failed to create directory via template 
        ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_XXXXXX’: No such file or directory
```

The mktemp command fails, because the script that calls it or mktemp itself do not create a missing directory.

And in fact on this system, the folder `/var/tmp` was missing, due to a problem with the system between keyboard and chair :(  . After restoring the folder, the removal process could continue and the issue was fixed.

Comment: Nice troubleshooting job! Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

Try

ls /boot

View the vmilinuz-version files for their versions

Then, for the ones you want removed:

sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends linux-image-version

I do not use apt autoremove, because it frequently makes a mess of things.

Comment: This strategy sucessfully removes the problematic old kernels at first glance, but running an apt-get command afterwards again shows that apt-get still tries and fails to fully remove these kernels, as before.

Comment: Over more than a decade, I've never found autoremove, used properly, to 'make a mess of things'.  If you have discovered a flaw in apt's logic that causes, problems, please file a bug report so it can be fixed.

Comment: @user535733 Yeah same here & I would have said same a week ago. I had never had this happen to me using autoremove. But, it just happened twice in the last week under 16.04.5 (different machines). (Only for a single kernel version - not multiple like OP). Was easy enough to clean up - I just deleted the offending file autoremove skipped under /boot. (was `/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic` for me - `dpkg` had shown `rc` for it). Re-ran apt/update-grub/etc .. all is well.