# ubuntu package update: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms missing

Tags: apt, 18.04, kernel

I'm just doing my usual weekly update of packages on my Ubuntu machines, and Something Went Wrong (TM).    I'm seeing this in the output of "sudo apt upgrade"

```
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic (4.15.0-36.39) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

I've seen other posts about fixing missing dkms stuff, but they all seem to involve deleting files or directories, and I'm a little hesitant to do that with kernel stuff.

I tried:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

but that seems to complain about the same missing file.

Is there some invocation that will let Ubuntu fix this error?

UPDATE:  nothing seems to be working to fix this.   `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` both try to install new kernels, but then return

`/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.`

followed by

`Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic
 linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

I'm starting to think I'm completely screwed and will have no choice but to re-install Ubuntu (again. sigh.)

Comment: Please take a look at this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952882/errors-every-time-i-use-apt-install-because-of-old-kernels). Regards,

Comment: You can also take a look to this [older post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227258/error-could-not-locate-dkms-conf-file).

Comment: PSA: it works with all dkms error for me the error message is `Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/rts_pstor/1.11/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
   ...fail!
`

Answer (score 4):

Took a while to find this, but I tracked it down.

First, run this command to find the offending "thing"

```
for i in /var/lib/dkms/*/[^k]*/source; do [ -e "$i" ] || echo "$i";done
```

In my case, it spit out

```
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-340/340.106/source
```

Take a deep breath and get rid of that directory

```
sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-340/340.106/source
```

Now run your updates:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Footnotes/Credits:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=151965

https://8thstring.blogspot.com/2012/01/error-could-not-locate-dkmsconf-file.html